# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1083 (42000): Field separator argument is not what is expected

Tags: python, mysql, csv, mysql-connector-python

When I use Jupyter notebook (Python) to connect MySQL using mysql.connector and load csv file into database, after creating cursor, I tried:

```
    self.cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'deficiency.csv' \
    REPLACE INTO TABLE retailstore.deficiency CHARACTER SET utf8 \
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' \
    IGNORE 1 LINES")
```

And I got the error message "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1083 (42000): Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual".

When I used the exactly same sql query directly in MySQL to load csv file, it works, while failed in Python.

Could someone help me identify where the problem is? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just `print`ing the SQL string you're trying to run before passing it to `self.cursor.execute`?

If you do, you'll get this output:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'deficiency.csv'     REPLACE INTO TABLE retailstore.deficiency CHARACTER SET utf8     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ' ESCAPED BY ' LINES TERMINATED BY '
'     IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Take a careful look at this and you'll note a couple of things about it:

- `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` and `ESCAPED BY` are followed only by a `'`, not `'"'` as you may expect,
- There's a line break after `TERMINATED BY '`.

To fix it, you need to escape the double-quote characters after `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` and `ESCAPED BY`, and also the backslashes in `\r\n`:

```
self.cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'deficiency.csv' \
REPLACE INTO TABLE retailstore.deficiency CHARACTER SET utf8 \
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' \
IGNORE 1 LINES")
```

Alternatively, if you use a triple-quoted rawstring, you don't need to escape the double-quote characters and the backslashes in `\r\n`, and you also don't need the trailing backslashes at the end of each line:

```
self.cursor.execute(r"""LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'deficiency.csv'
    REPLACE INTO TABLE retailstore.deficiency CHARACTER SET utf8
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES""")
```

You may be wondering why your original code generated the output it did.  The reason is that you actually have three string literals next to one another.  One of them is

```
"LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'deficiency.csv' \
    REPLACE INTO TABLE retailstore.deficiency CHARACTER SET utf8 \
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"
```

the next one is

```
' ESCAPED BY '
```

(string literals in Python can be surrounded by `'` or `"`) and the last one is

```
"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' \
IGNORE 1 LINES"
```

If you put two string literals next to one another, Python will concatenate them together:

```
>>> print("12"'34'"56")
123456
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the revised code while it returned another error message saying "mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"...Could you please suggest any clue on that?

Comment: @Ramona: sorry, no, I haven't come across that message before.